# How to map the results of my JSON data file in quasar table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm actually VueJS studdent and I can't seem to return the distances from my JSON file to a table.
What's the best practice to return all the data of "5", "10" ... by walking and driving please ?

this.concurrentsRows = JSON.parse(result.data.result.iso.driving[i].poi[j].distance) ???

How to define i and j ?

My file VueJS(Quasar):

```
<template>
 <div>
  <SimpleTableFirstCell
    :loading="loading"
    :columns="concurrentsColums"
    :rows="concurrentsRows"
    :title="Concurrents List"
  />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

import SimpleTableFirstCell from 'src/components/SimpleTableFirstCell.vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Concurrents',

  components: {,
    SimpleTableFirstCell
  },
  data () {
    return {
      concurrentsColums: [
        {
          name: 'distance',
          label: 'Distance',
          field: 'distance',
        },
        {
          name: 'latitude',
          label: 'Latitude',
          field: 'latitude',
        },
        {
          name: 'longitude',
          label: 'Longitude',
          field: 'longitude',
        }
      ],
      loading: ref(false),

      concurrentsRows: ref([]),
    }
  },
  methods: {
    concurrentsData () {
     
        axios.get('https://url...')
         .then(result => {
           this.loading = true
           this.concurrentsRows = JSON.parse(result.data.result)
         .finally(() => {
           loading.value = false
         })
    }
   }
  })
</script>
```

My JSON:

```
[
  {
    "iso": {
      "driving": {
        "5": {
          "poi": [
            {
              "distance": 1.67168887573,
              "latitude": "50.415",
              "longitude": "2.990",
            },
            {
              "distance": 3.68833575679,
              "latitude": "50.403",
              "longitude": "3.031",
            },
          ],
        },
        "10": {
          "poi": [
            {
              "distance": 2.40512340917,
              "latitude": "50.412",
              "longitude": "2.977",
            },
            {
              "distance": 2.11846991875,
              "latitude": "50.417",
              "longitude": "2.975",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      "walking": {
        "5": {
          "poi": [
            {
            "distance": 3.68833575679,
            "latitude": "50.403",
              "longitude": "3.031",
            }
          ],
        },
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"How to define i and j ?"*? With `var` or `let` typically.. they seem to be typically used with `for` or any loop in general. Can you loop through `result.data.result`? Is that not an array already? Axios should have parsed the JSON for you I'm pretty sure. Just make `console.log` calls if you are not sure what a value is.

Comment: Axios does send me a data table, but I cannot retrieve the POIs in the table. Do you have to write a function that iterates "driving" and "poi"? Where to place it?

Comment: Pretty sure you will have to write a loop for iterating them, yes. You can probably just do `let values = result.data.result;` and do the for loop then to make `this.concurrentsRows` whatever you need.

Comment: This is the loop that I can't do, it must iterate "walking", "driving" and the "poi"

Comment: Well but why can't you? If you can see them as an object in the network tab you can make a loop over everything (or a loop in a loop.. you get the idea).

Comment: Yes i need to loop within a loop, i just figured out how to do it. Thank you

Comment: Hey great, at least you learned something  I'll answer the same below that the solution was found.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `j` are typically used for the `for` loop. A simple one:

```js
let arr = [2, 4, 8];
for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, arr[i]);
}
```

In your case you can have a `for` loop within a `for` loop.

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3], [2,4,8], [-1,-1]];
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  for(let j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(i, j, arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Likewise objects can be traversed with `for...in`. Example here:

```js
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

See

- [JavaScript for documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [JavaScript for...in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)